# Would this question be on topic on the main site?

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to pose this question: **How many secret or hidden passages is the Vatican historically recorded to have possessed?**

Would this question be allowed on the main site?

Note Bene: There is no Vatican tag. Would it be okay for me to create one, thus avoid using the tag for Rome or untagged?

Comment: If they are recorded, they aren't exactly secret.

Comment: @T.E.D.  Some passages have been made known public on various occasions and for diverse reasons.

Comment: I'd suggest putting out examples of that in the question then. Aside from that, I'm honestly not sure. A lot depends on how well the question is crafted.

Comment: @T.E.D. Thanks, It seems to be doing okay on main for the present moment.

Comment: Yes. So far your answer appears to be "yes". :-)

Comment: I would agree with that. And I really look forward to seeing the details. Go ahead, OP, and post that question! What's the worst that could happen?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica See [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34849/vatican-hidden-secret-rooms-and-passages)